# Javascript search with includes for each DIV

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a filter function with includes. As for now, I have 3 main DIV, and each main DIV has its own DIV. The current script I have now only worked on main DIV.

Instead of highlighting main DIV, I only want to highlight matched char DIV.

For example, when key in 'inner', Inner First and Inner Sec will be highlighted. When key in 'Inner First', only DIV for Inner First will be highlighted.

Would appreciate if anyone of you can help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    if (input.value !== '') {
      if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        for (j = 0; j < nodes[i].length; j++) {
          nodes[j].style.backgroundColor = "";
          if (input.value !== '') {
            if (nodes[j].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
              nodes[j].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
              for (k = 0; k < nodes[j].length; k++) {
                nodes[k].style.backgroundColor = "";
                if (input.value !== '') {
                  if (nodes[k].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
                    nodes[k].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                  } else {
                    nodes[k].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                  }
                }
              }
            } else {
              nodes[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<table align="center" width="20%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
      <input type="text" id="Search" title="Type in a name">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Click to search
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div class="target">
  This is my DIV element.
  <div class="target">
    Inner First
    <div class="target">
      Inner Sec
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="target">
  This is another Div element.
</div>
<div class="target">
  Can you find me?
</div>
```

Comment: everything gets highlighted with different colors, what do you mean by "highlight"? can you please clarify the meaning of the different colors in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do (what's a "char div"?), but I know you only need to check if `input.value !== ''` once, not every time you iterate over another set of nodes...

Comment: you are looping using different index variable names. `i`, `j`, `k`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `node.innerText` also gives the text of the child elements. To fix this, you should use `node.childNodes[0].nodeValue` which will only give the node's text.

Moreover, you are doing nested loops but referencing incorrectly:

`for (j = 0; j < nodes[i].length; j++)`.

*`nodes[i].length` here is `undefined`. Maybe you mean `nodes[i].children.length`?*

Also, your code is hard to follow with all the nested loops which does the same thing and just differ in color. I suggest you make a recursive function.

Please see below function if I what I'm thinking is correct. I guess you wanted to put different colors depending of the level of the node in the heirarchy. *(Open your developer tool to see `console.log` outputs)*

```js
var input;
var filter;
var nodes;
var colors;

function myFunction() {
  //initialize variables
  input = document.getElementById("Search");
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  // store colors here for accessing via index
  colors = ['blue', 'grey', 'yellow', 'green'];

  if (filter !== '') {
    updateNodesBg(nodes); //neat
  }
}

function updateNodesBg(lNodes, colorIdx) {
  colorIdx = colorIdx || 0; // this will be the index of the color

  for (var i = 0; i < lNodes.length; i++) {
    var currentNode = lNodes[i];
    var currentText = currentNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var innerText = currentNode.innerText;
    console.log('currentText and innerText EQUAL?', currentText === innerText);
    if (currentText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      currentNode.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIdx]; //pass in the index to get the color
    } else {
      currentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //else, we should color red
    }
    if (currentNode.children && currentNode.children.length > 0) {
      updateNodesBg(currentNode.children, colorIdx + 1); //if the node has children, call `updateNodesBg` recursively
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table align="center" width="20%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
      <input type="text" id="Search" title="Type in a name">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Click to search
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div class="target">
  This is my DIV element.
  <div class="target">
    Inner First 1
    <div class="target">
      Inner Sec 1
      <div>Inner Third 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="target">
      Inner Sec 2
      <div>Inner Third 1</div>
      <div>Inner Third 2
        <div>Inner Fourth 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="target">
    Inner First 2
    <div class="target">
      Inner Sec 2
      <div>Inner Third 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="target">
  This is another Div element.
</div>
<div class="target">
  Can you find me?
</div>
```

Note that [`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) has different returns depending on the type of the node:

```
Node                    Value of nodeValue
  CDATASection              Content of the CDATA section
  Comment                   Content of the comment
  Document                  null
  DocumentFragment          null
  DocumentType              null
  Element                   null
  NamedNodeMap              null
  EntityReference           null
  Notation                  null
  ProcessingInstruction     Entire content excluding the target
  Text                      Content of the text node
```

Comment: @MattEllen, in the OP's case it is.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the text is in the current div, then in any child divs.

`InnerText` and `textContent` both concatenate text of the parent and all children, so you'll need to figure out where the text is actually coming from.

I do this recursively, because I don't think you'll have that many layers of divs. If there is a lot of nesting, then you'd need to take an iterative approach

```js
function myFunction()
{
  let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
  targets.forEach(target => target.style.background = 'white');
  let filterText = document.getElementById('Search').value;
  if(filterText != '')
  {
    let result = [...targets].filter(target => target.textContent.includes(filterText));
    result.forEach(r => { checkSelf(r, filterText); checkKids(r, filterText); });
  }
}

function checkSelf(element, filterText)
{
  let selfText = element.textContent;
  for(let child of element.children)
  { 
    selfText = selfText.replace(child.textContent, '');
  }
  if(selfText.includes(filterText))
  {
    element.style.background = 'limegreen';
  }
  else
  {
    element.style.background = 'white';
  }
}

function checkKids(element, filterText)
{
  for(let child of element.children)
  {
    if(!child.textContent.includes(filterText))
    {
      child.style.background = 'white';
    }
    else
    {
      checkKids(child, filterText);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table align="center" width="20%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
      <input type="text" id="Search" title="Type in a name">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Click to search
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div class="target">
  This is my DIV element.
  <div class="target">
    Inner First
    <div class="target">
      Inner Sec
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="target">
  This is another Div element.
</div>
<div class="target">
  Can you find me?
</div>
```